# Restoring filenames of files recovered after deletion.

Tags: windows-7

I accidently formatted one of 4 partitions I had on my hard disk. I used several disk recovery programs to recover my files. Though I recovered most of my files, the problem is I didn't recover them by their names. The whole directory structure was destroyed and all recovered files were clustered in a single folder with numbers. Could you please help me recover my files with their old existing names and directory structure.

Comment: can you name the recovery software you used?

Comment: You'll have to use different data recovery programs in the hope that one of them can help you, but depending on the extent of data loss/damage to the file table what you've managed to retrieve already might be all that's possible.

Comment: assuming you have not been writing to the disk in question, try a partition level recovery tool like Testdisk. with file carving tools like the one you used, all the name, location, and other metadata on the files is lost, because that information is stored in the file system index tables, not in the files themselves. There is nothing you can do to recover the file names or directory information for the files you have already recovered.

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible for restore the name due to the file structure being damaged.

According to your description, you should have tried multiple different file recovery tools. Most of the processional file recovery tools support rebuilding the file/directory structure so that we can get the original file name.

But if the file/directory structure is destroyed, you will not be able to get the files name back.

Answer (score 0):

The correct process, for next time: Image the partition/disk (something like linux' dd); keep one as a master, then mount and work on a duplicate image, not the disk.

testdisk would have been the first thing to try: to re-instate the partiton table, then you could have accessed everything as normal.

Assuming you used a windows recovery tool, there is no option now, to reassemble or rename the recovered flies/fragments.

Your best option, if you haven't written over the original partition, you could try scalpel or dd-rescue to pull fiies at a low level.